# (Get-wmiobject win32_computersystem).username returns invalid value

Tags: windows, powershell

In windows 8.1 English OS/64-bit PC logged on with Microsoft Account
When i execute the above command the User name format will be as follows
//

In windows 8.1 Japanese OS/64-bit PC logged on with Microsoft Account
When i execute the above command the User name format will be as follows
/

Note: 
System Name: lenovo-PC
DomainName: LENOVO-PC
UserName: TestAccount

Why it is returning different format in the different environment PC?

My logic is failing to get the token for the current logged in User.

Please help anyone.

Comment: Are you looking for the currently logged in user or the current user that runs your PowerShell instance?

Comment: Show us the output that you are getting from the query when you run in PS and also tell us your expectations. If you are using Dot and picking only username then it will only return `Domain\username`. Also if you are running the query and not specifying any property then it will not return username; it will return Domain,Manufacturer,Model, Name, PrimaryOwnerName,TotalPhysicalmemory by defauly. `username` is an extended property

Comment: **Currently logged in user **@buttercup

Comment: The  output will be <lenovo-pc>/<LENOVO-PC>/<TestAccount> @RanadipDutta

Comment: If you wish to get the output like this then you should create a custom object and assign the values to it .

Comment: What kind of condition is returning the username format in such a way.@RanadipDutta

Comment: @RanadipDutta If I understood his question right, he is not asking for how to fix this, but rather why his instance outputs that. (because normally <systemname> is not part of the output)

Comment: you are right @buttercup

Comment: @DeepakHirapur: Posted as an answer.

Comment: @buttercup: Ahh, I see.. then it should not be in SO because it is primarily opinion based. Also, the answer is because it belongs to the same dot net class.

Comment: @buttercup,@Randip Dutta Guys any idea?

Comment: What do you get when you do `(Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName`?

Comment: Did you mean to remove `( Get-WMiObject Win32_ComputerSystem ).Domain` from your question? It now says "When I execute the above command", but there is no above command. /confused -- Also, are you logged into a remote server? If you're executing locally, it will not return a value. Try [RDC-ing](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-use-microsofts-remote-desktop-connection) into a server and try again.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get the username. Here are some examples:

```
(get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem).username
```

or

```
[Environment]::UserName
```

or

```
whoami
```

or

```
[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
```

For your specific problem, try this:

```
$domain = $env:UserDomain
$user = $env:UserName
$username = "$domain\$user"
```

Comment: Thanks @buttercup i worried Why PC Name is retrieving from the above WMI Query?

Comment: `$(Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select username).username` and  `(Get-wmiobject win32_computersystem).username` will return same value.